# I can't display a variable

Tags: angular, typescript

**the column tariff 1** is the variable `FRAIS_ETRANGERS` linked to `CODE:"NEK01",` the variable is displayed in the template.

**the column tariff 2** is the variable `FRAIS_ETRANGERS` linked to `CODE:"NEK03",` I am unable to display this variable in the template.

[image]

I don't understand why I can't display tariff 2?

Here is the code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let plnPlcInfo of tarificationTitre">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let svmInfo of plnPlcInfo.PLN_SVM">
        <tr class="text-center">
            <td>
                <ng-container *ngIf="svmInfo.PLN[0].CODE === 'NEK01'">
                    {{ svmInfo.PLN[0].PLAGE[0].FRAIS_ETRANGERS }} %
                </ng-container>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ng-container *ngIf="svmInfo.PLN[0].CODE === 'NEK03'">
                    {{ svmInfo.PLN[0].PLAGE[0].FRAIS_ETRANGERS }}
                </ng-container>
            </td>

            <td scope="col">{{ svmInfo.SVM }}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

and the service

```
export class TodoService {

   PLN_PLC = [
      {
        PLACECODE: 26,
        PLACELABEL: "Fundsettle",
        PLN_SVM: [
          {
            SVM: 16111801,
            ISIN: "LU0100749679",
            LABEL: "NEKR FD LIFESTYLE DYNAMICC",
            PLN: [
               {
                  CODE:"NEK01",
                  PLAN:8,
                  CANAL:"*",
                  AV:"A",
                  LIB:"Fonds Amenkor 8",
                  DATEV_EFFECTIVE:"0001-01-01",
                  PLAGE:[
                     {
                        BORNE:9999999999999.99,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:1,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:1,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:2.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  CODE:"NEK01",
                  PLAN:8,
                  CANAL:"*",
                  AV:"V",
                  LIB:"Fonds Amenkor 8",
                  DATEV_EFFECTIVE:"0001-01-01",
                  PLAGE:[
                     {
                        BORNE:9999999999999.99,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:1,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:1,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  CODE:"NEK03",
                  PLAN:8,
                  CANAL:"*",
                  AV:"A",
                  LIB:"Fonds Amenkor 8 - Staff",
                  DATEV_EFFECTIVE:"0001-01-01",
                  PLAGE:[
                     {
                        BORNE:9999999999999.99,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:1,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:1,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:1.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  CODE:"NEK03",
                  PLAN:8,
                  CANAL:"*",
                  AV:"V",
                  LIB:"Fonds Amenkor 8 - Staff",
                  DATEV_EFFECTIVE:"0001-01-01",
                  PLAGE:[
                     {
                        BORNE:9999999999999.99,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:1,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:1,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
  
    constructor() {}
    
  }
```

I created an illustration via [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/kora1348/tarif?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftodo%2Ftodo.component.html).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at your data structure, you will see that `svmInfo.PLN[0].CODE` is always equal to `NEK01` so `*ngIf="svmInfo.PLN[0].CODE === 'NEK03'"` will never evaluate to true.

You may need to loop through your index for `PLN` as well since the following values are set:

```
svmInfo.PLN[0].CODE = "NEK01"
svmInfo.PLN[1].CODE = "NEK01"
svmInfo.PLN[2].CODE = "NEK03"
svmInfo.PLN[3].CODE = "NEK03"
```